# how to prevent duplicate or repeat during upload csv file to database in cake php

Tags: sql-server, cakephp, csv

i'm trying to upload my **CSV** file to database in cake php, i face a problem - if i upload the file twice , the data will also insert twice. How to prevent duplicate data upload into database? what function should add in to controller? Please help,
thanks!

```
public function upload()
{
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $up_file = $this->request->data['Upload']['CSV_File'];
        if($up_file['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
        { 
            move_uploaded_file($up_file['tmp_name'], ROOT . DS . 'uploads' . DS . $up_file['name']);

    $file = fopen(ROOT . DS . 'uploads' . DS . $up_file['name'], 'r');
    $fields = fgetcsv($file);
            unset($this->request->data['Upload']['CSV_File']);
            while(! feof($file))
            {
                $curDataRow = fgetcsv($file);
                $i = 0;
                foreach($fields as $key => $field_name)
                {
                    if(strtolower($field_name) == 'date')
                    { 
                        $date = $curDataRow[$i];



                    $this->request->data['Upload'][$field_name] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($curDataRow[$i]));


                    }
                    else if (strtolower($field_name) == 'time')
                    { $this->request->data['Upload'][$field_name] = date('H:i:s', strtotime($curDataRow[$i])); }
                    else
                    { $this->request->data['Upload'][$field_name] = $curDataRow[$i];}

                    $i++;
                }
                    $count = $this->Upload->find('count', array(         
                    'conditions' => array(
                    'RAS_Code' => $this->data['Upload']['RAS_Code'],
                    'Date' => $this->data['Upload']['Date'],
                    'Time' => $this->data['Upload']['Time'],
                    'SOF' => $this->data['Upload']['SOF'], )));
                    if ($count>0)
                    unset($this->request->data['Upload']['CSV_File']);


$this->Upload->save($this->request->data, array('validate' => true));               }

            fclose($file);
```

Comment: You need to provide more info, such as your code, before anyone can provide useful help.

Answer (score 1):

1. The code you want doesn't belong to the controller, all data processing code goes into models
2. The solution to your problem is simple: Before saving validate if there is a duplicate of the record present. You just need to do a find('count') for all fields and  their values. If your result is greater than zero you've got a duplicate and skip the save. Easy.
3. Follow some coding standard, your code is horrible to read.

Comment: thank you for your comment.I’m sorry i’m new learner to cake php. RAS_Code, Date, Time, SOF is the field in my database table, i want this four field combination to determine the data entry during upload is unique. Above i've added find('count') code not sure where is the mistake.